# making all input fields borders red when no one at least was filled in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am not good enough with javascript. Simply I have a form with some input fields. The user has to fill in at least one of them. I had already found the right code to do this. This code tells the user there is an error using an alert message. But I want to make all input fields borders red instead of this alert message using the same code.

**HTML**

```
<form  id="myform" action="" method="post">
    <input name="destination" class="form-control" type="text" >
    <input name="thingstodo" class="form-control" type="text">
    <input name="gsearch" class="form-control" type="text">
    <button type="submit" name="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
  $("#myform").submit(function(){

    var valid=0;
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() != "") valid+=1;
    });

    if(valid){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("error: you must fill in at least one field");
        return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: This is an easy change, but I would point out that highlighting all fields in red - from a UX perspective indicates that all fields are required rather than just one. I would reconsider this UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by setting the CSS style. This is done most easily with jQuery syntax.

```
$(function(){
  $("#myform").submit(function(){

    var valid = 0; 
    $(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() != "") { 
        valid++;
        $(this).css("border-color", "initial");
      }
      else {
        $(this).css("border-color", "red");
      }
    });

    if (valid > 0) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
  });
});
```

Comment: There is a problem still here in this code. Even after filling in one field . the action doesn't go ahead

Comment: sorry I don't know what you mean by "the action doesn't go ahead". Here's a working example of the code I've posted: https://jsfiddle.net/q5xub1Le/ Obviously when you submit with all the fields valid, nothing happens because there's no server-side code in that example. But it shows you that the validation catches empty fields and highlights them in red.

Comment: I don't have to fill in the three fields, one field to be filled would be enough, Here I will not be able to press on search button till I fill in all fields.

Comment: Ok i see. Sorry, I misunderstood. See this version: https://jsfiddle.net/q5xub1Le/2/ and the edit to the answer above

Answer (score 1):

Modify the code like so

```
$(function(){
$("#myform").submit(function(){

var valid=0;
$(this).find('input[type=text]').each(function(){

    if($(this).val() != "") valid+=1;
 else
 $(this).style.border = "solid 1px red"
});

if(valid){
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
 });
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't actually provide the behaviour the user specified, rather than highlight each field you have highlighted the form element.

Comment: This is true @Yoda. How to highlight each field separately instead of highlight the whole form element?

Comment: you're right. i just modified it accordingly. try this one out

Comment: I tried this code @lhavCoder. But return is true even if all fields are still empty

Answer (score 0):

**How about this ?**

```js
$(function(){
  $("#myform").submit(function(){
    var dirty = false;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        if($(this).val().length){
          dirty = true;
        }
    });
    if(!dirty){
      $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
        $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  id="myform" action="" method="post">
    <input name="destination" class="form-control" type="text" >
    <input name="thingstodo" class="form-control" type="text">
    <input name="gsearch" class="form-control" type="text">
    <button type="submit" name="search">Search</button>
</form>
```